# Apache - Too many redirects due to a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting

I'am facing a tomcat with apache as a reverse proxy.
URL: http://zvprod.cbc.local/ Works fine.
*you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!*

i just want a rewrite or redirect to **/zvhtml**
from http://zvprod.cbc.local to http://zvprod.cbc.local/zvhtml

Tried different Rules, there is always a browser error "too many redirects"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zvprod.cbc.local

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule .* http://zvprod.cbc.local/zvhtml [R=301,L]

    <Location />
      Require all granted
    </Location>

    HostnameLookups         Off

    UseCanonicalName        Off
    ServerSignature         On

    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On

    ProxyPass               / http://172.22.16.10:60131/
    ProxyPassReverse        / http://172.22.16.10:60131/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: rewrite and redirect or two different things . rewrite makes http://zvprod.cbc.local look like http://zvprod.cbc.local/zvhtml, redirects makes everyone who vists former to visit later. Which do you exactly need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule .* http://zvprod.cbc.local/zvhtml [R=301,L]
```

is wrong because it matches all traffic, and then ends in an infinite loop. Instead, try

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://zvprod.cbc.local/zvhtml [R=301,L]
```